# MAPIMessage's getdate function returning ChunkNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache's poi hsmf to process .msg outlook files.

When I try to retrieve date using MAPI's getdate function it throws a ChunkNotFound Exception, I do not know what is going wrong.

Here is the code snippet

MAPIMessage msg  = new MAPIMessage("TestFolder/"+Filename);

```
  String Result = msg.getSubject(); // works

Calendar CaObj = msg.getMessageDate(); ->Throws a ChunkNotFoundException here
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ChunkNotFoundException is being thrown because there's no chunk in the file containing the message date

By default, MAPIMessage will thrown a ChunkNotFoundException when you ask for something that isn't there. If you want, you can change that so it returns Null instead. Just call [setReturnNullOnMissingChunk(true)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hsmf/MAPIMessage.html#setReturnNullOnMissingChunk%28boolean%29) on it first, then you'll get nulls instead

Comment: Thanks, But I need to retrieve those date time stamp.Don't all msg files have timestamps? Is there any other way to retrieve timestamps from these files?

Comment: Only emails that have been sent will have a message submission timestamp, which is what getMessageDate returns. There may be other dates in a file that hasn't been sent, but you'd need to enumerate the chunks looking for one that's a date to find it

Comment: It could be a bug, as reported here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57744
Fixed in apache poi 3.11

Comment: @Zardo fix-length properties still aren't quite handled correctly, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53784